# Send all Request to Inside folder in php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory, subdirectory

[sharedHostingFolder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ccWp.png)

[folder1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppHRz.png)

[folder2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJPcn.png)

[folder3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szEtY.png)

[xampp htdocs folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lgfF.png)

## Folder Structure:

```
root/sharedHostingFolder
-need an .htaccess file here
-folder1
        --index.php
        --dude.php
-folder2
        --hello.php
        --index.php
        ---folder5
                       ----index.php
-folder3
        --hi.php
        --index.php
```

## Request Structure

```
Request "root/sharedHostingFolder/hello.php"         will show file inside   "root/sharedHostingFolder/folder2/hello.php"

Request "root/sharedHostingFolder/"                  will show file inside   "root/sharedHostingFolder/folder2/index.php"

Request "root/sharedHostingFolder/folder1/dude.php"  will show file inside   "root/sharedHostingFolder/folder1/dude.php"

Request "root/sharedHostingFolder/folder1/"          will show file inside   "root/sharedHostingFolder/folder1/index.php"

Request "root/sharedHostingFolder/folder2/hello.php" will show file inside   "root/sharedHostingFolder/folder2/hello.php"

Request "root/sharedHostingFolder/folder2/"          will show file inside   "root/sharedHostingFolder/folder2/index.php"

Request "root/sharedHostingFolder/folder3/hi.php"    will show file inside   "root/sharedHostingFolder/folder3/hi.php"

Request "root/sharedHostingFolder/folder5/"          will show file inside   "root/sharedHostingFolder/folder2/folder5/index.php"
```

I HAVE NO ACCESS TO php.ini file

### .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder1/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder2/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder3/
RewriteRule - [END]
RewriteRule ^ /folder2%{REQUEST_URI} [END]
```

### httpd.conf file:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

### Error:

```
object not found
```

I researched and found out .htaccess will do that easily . But, Really I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Are these subfolders of www independent sites? If so you may be better off using Apache virtual hosts, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: No, website.com/F1/www

Comment: @MixUp - Is it a multiple website subdirectories configuration?

Comment: It is an shared hosting mean  I am allocated F1 directory in domain root folder consisting of 3 folder F1,F2,F3. and my F1 folder has 3 directory 1.PHP ,2.ADMIN 3.USERS. .   I want all request to go to USERS directory except domain/admin and domain/php request to their respective directory.please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a strange question. TO me it reads a bit like a classical xy problem... As if you did not ask how to solve your actual task, but how to get something to work that you think *might* solve your task...

Anyway, looking at your examples I have the impression that little is to be done, mostly some *exceptions* that need to be implemented as rewriting rules. So something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sharedHostingFolder/folder1/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sharedHostingFolder/folder2/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sharedHostingFolder/folder3/
RewriteRule - [END]

RewriteRule ^ /sharedHostingFolder/folder2%{REQUEST_URI} [END]
```

This leaves requests to URIs starting with one of the folder names untouched, replying on classical file system mapping and defining the `index.php` script as fallback logic for those folders. And it maps everything else into `folder2`.

It does not get clear from your question what that "www" string is meant to represent. If that is meant to represent another folder level then you might have to add that level to the rules above.

For this to work the rewriting module needs to be enabled, obviously. Best is to implement such rules in the http server's host configuration. If you do not have access to that you can also use a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"), but you need to enable the interpretation of such file for the requested location (see the apache documentation about the `AllowOverride` directive).

Comment: now after edit of question  please check it

Comment: The only difference I can spot is that you renamed what has formerly been "www" to "root/sharedHostingFolder". Since you again fail to explain that there is nothing more I can learn from that. I already pointed out that you might have to adjust the rules according to such prefixes.

Comment: I cannot offer further help without you giving more specific information. "Not working" never helped, it only raises questions. What does that actually mean? What happens? What issues?

Comment: see `httpd.conf`file

Comment: As already written you need to adjust the rules I posted to your actual file system layout. You did not do that in the rule set you now added to your question. Also I would like to repeat the suggestion that you actually _explain_ what "www" actually stands for (or now "root/sharedHositngFolder" after you changed that in the question). Your description and the folder layout contradict each other, so you will need to be more precise there.

Comment: So it is _not_ actually part of the path as your description suggests. And the requests actually go to "/sharedHostingFolder/folder..." unlike your description suggests... I adjusted the paths in the rule set I posted. That should match, unless there are additional oddities here.

Comment: Quite frankly I fail to see the idea behind that "sharedHostingFolder" folder. Why do you use it? What for?